# Output matching lines from 3 text files and also the line under the matching line

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have a question regarding common data. I have three text files which consist of data in the following format:

```
    cli= 111
    mon= 45

    cli= 584
    mon= 21

    cli= 23
    mon= 417
```

Now I have the following program whcih when I execute it, it gives me all the matching CLI. In other words it gives me the CLI that appeared in the 3 text files.

```
    with open ('/home/user/Desktop/text1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open ('/home/user/Desktop/text2.txt', 'r') as file2:
            with open ('/home/user/Desktop/text3.txt', 'r') as file3:
                    same = set(file1).intersection(file2).intersection(file3)
same.discard('\n')

with open ('/home/user/Desktop/common.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
            file_out.write(line)
```

My question is, can I also output the value (MON= 45) together with CLI= 111? Let's say CLI= 111 is present in ALL of the 3 text files. I want a result something like this:

```
    cli= 111
    mon= 45
    mon= 98
    mon= 32
```

Thanks in advance.
PS: The above sample data is of just 1 text file. Assume there are 3 text files. Thanks!

Comment: So you want the corresponding mon after each cli that appears in all files?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham exactly!

Comment: Ah ok, well that is easy do with a dict, I will throw something together

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: are you just matching specific lines with cli= or any lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are throwing away the data you want to later access. Without having to parse the files again, you need to somehow capture that data so you don't end up looking at a file again. A way to do that (assuming that each 'cli' only has one corresponding 'mon' per file) would be with a dictionary.

I have made a function that builds a Dictionary out of a provided file where the keys are the 'cli' data and the values are the mon data. From there, you can build a Set() out of the Dictionary keys and find the intersection that way. From the intersection, you know that the returned values MUST be keys in the Dictionary, so just concatenate them to an 'out' string and write that to your out file :)

```
    def buildDict(f):
        dic = {}
        for i in range(0,len(f)):
            if "cli" in f[i]:
                dic[f[i]] = f[i+1]
        return dic

    with open ('1.txt', 'r') as file1:
        f1_dic = buildDict(file1.readlines())
        with open ('2.txt', 'r') as file2:
            f2_dic = buildDict(file2.readlines())
            with open ('3.txt', 'r') as file3:
                f3_dic = buildDict(file3.readlines())
                same = set(f1_dic.keys()).intersection(f2_dic.keys()).intersection(f3_dic.keys())

    out = ''
    for i in same:
        out += i
        out += f1_dic[i]
        out += f2_dic[i]
        out += f3_dic[i]


    with open ('common.txt', 'w') as file_out:
        file_out.write(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the data in a dict pulling the line after cli's that are in all files:

```
with open('text1.txt', 'r') as file1, open('text2.txt', 'r') as file2, open('text3.txt', 'r') as file3:
    inter = set(file1).intersection(file2).intersection(file3)

    # create a dict using lists as values to group the mons and remove empty lines
    d = {k: [] for k  in inter if k.strip()}
    # don't need set anymore, dict lookups are also O(1)
    del inter
    # reset pointers
    file1.seek(0), file2.seek(0), file3.seek(0)

    # iterate over files again
    for f in [file1, file2, file3]:
        for line in f:
            if line in d:
                # pull next line if we get a match.
                d[line].append(next(f))
```

Then just write the dict content:

```
with open('/home/user/Desktop/common.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for k,v in d.items():
        file_out.write(k)
        for line in v:
            file_out.write(line)
```

If you are looking for a particular line i.e starting with *cli=* then another approach would be to build the dict first with the file1 data then iterate over the remainder, when you go to write only write the data where the value/ list length is == 3:

```
with open('text1.txt', 'r') as file1, open('text2.txt', 'r') as file2, open(
        'text3.txt', 'r') as file3:
    # create dict from inital file storing following line after cli-.. inside list as value
    d = {k: [next(file1)] for k in file1 if k.starstwith("cli=")}

    for f in [file2, file3]:
        for line in f:
            if line in d:
                d[line].append(next(f))

with open('/home/user/Desktop/common.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for k, v in d.items():
        # if len is three we have one from each
        if len(v) == 3:
            file_out.write(k)
            for line in v:
                file_out.write(line)
```

The only way this will fail is if you have a file or files that has a repeating cli=...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting hack you've got there for building sets of lines on the fly; but as you see it's just a bit too clever, since the `mon` lines get separated from the `cli` lines. So let's try reading more carefully so that this doesn't happen:

```
import re

def getfile(fname):
    with open(fname) as file1:
        text = file1.read()
    records = text.split("\n\n")
    return dict(re.search(r"cli= *(\d+)\nmon= *(\d+)", rec).groups() for rec in records)

d1 = getfile('/home/user/Desktop/text1.txt')
d2 = getfile('/home/user/Desktop/text2.txt')
d3 = getfile('/home/user/Desktop/text3.txt')
same = set(d1).intersection(d2).intersection(d3)

print("cli="+same)
print("mon="+d1[same])
print("mon="+d2[same])
print("mon="+d3[same])
```

I turned each file into a dictionary that maps `cli` values to `mon` values, since they come in pairs. Then we intersect the `cli` values and use them to look up the `mon` values.